# Sony e-reader opens Shotwell and displays content of /Media/Setting

Tags: default, ebooks, media, calibre

When I connect my Sony PRS-T1 e-reader Ubuntu 12.04 opens the Removable Media's default photo app (Shotwell) and then displays the contents of one of the two drives: /Media/Setting. The other drive is /Media/Reader. Both drives are mounted in the launcher, btw.

The only obvious way to prevent the above is to check "Never prompt or start media upon insertion" in System Settings / Details / Removable Media. But then I have to go without automatic launching of apps for CDs, DVDs and photos.

I'd like the e-reader to open Calibre (and also keep the other automagic stuff) but without the annoying aberrations. Does anyone know how?

I've read that I could add an empty document entitled .is_audio_device to the root of an MSC which will tell Ubuntu to open a USB stick, for example, as an audio device. Could I do the same with the ereader? But what would the title be? Would it be .is.ebook_device or .is.ereader_device or something else?

Thanks for your help.

Bingo

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary solution I disabled automount-open in Dconf: org/gnome/desktop/media-handling and also set Removable Media's Photos to "Do Nothing". At least now plugging in the e-reader won't open Shotwell or display the contents of the drives.

As to how to get the e-reader to be recognised as an e-reader and not a camera, and then to open Calibre automatically....

Comment: I know it's not the done thing to repeatedly answer your own questions. However, I thought someone might like to know that you can use Cuttlefish to open Calibre when your e-reader mounts. Having disabled all automounts I also added two additional instructions: an MP3 player launches Banshee, and a camera launches Shotwell. Bit of a clumsy workaround but better than nowt.